# What free audio file converters for Windows 7 support the broadest amount of sound file formats?

Tags: gratis, windows-7, audio, media-converter, file-converter

I would like to know what are the best free audio file converters which can be downloaded and installed as applications on Windows 7. I am looking for 3GPP to MP3 conversion in particular, but would like to have the app which can convert the most different types of sound files back and forth between one format and another available.

Comment: Gratis or paid? Which ones have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

[ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) can probably convert the widest range of audio formats, (video formats as well of course).

- Free
- Cross Platform

Comment: WinFF is a gentle inroduction to ffmpeg, on Windows. http://winff.org/html_new/

Answer (score 1):

The free software [VideoLAN](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html), also known as VLC, can convert files. If it does not support your codec, install the free [K-Lite Codec Pack (full)](http://www.codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_full.htm).

In VLC, go to `Media | Convert/save...` to convert files.

The 3GPP file format is a container format. That means it is not a file format per se but contains other file formats (e.g. an MPEG-4 video stream and an AAC-LC audio stream), so it's hard to guess what exactly you have and whether it'll work for sure.

Answer (score 1):

**[Format Factory](http://www.pcfreetime.com/)** is the best. It's free, a really nice interface,Can work seamlessly on windows and can convert a wide range of things audio,video and images too.

> Provides functions below: 
>   All to MP4/3GP/MPG/AVI/WMV/FLV/SWF
>  All to MP3/WMA/AMR/OGG/AAC/WAV
>  
>   All to JPG/BMP/PNG/TIF/ICO/GIF/TGA。  
>  
>   Rip DVD to video file,Rip Music CD to audio file.  
>  
>   MP4 files support iPod/iPhone/PSP/BlackBerry format.
>   Supports RMVB,Watermark,AV Mux.

Here's a Screenshot of the version i m using currently:

[image]